# AWS 'Bucket already exists' - how to "migrate" existing resources to CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We have already created some infrastructure manually and with terraform, including some s3 buckets. In the future I would like to use pure CloudFormation to define the infrastructure as code.

So I created a CloudFormation yaml definition which references an existing bucket:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  TheBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: my-existing-bucket-name
```

When I try to apply it, execution fails, with CloudFormation stack event:

```
The following resource(s) failed to update: [TheBucket].
12:33:47 UTC+0200   UPDATE_FAILED   AWS::S3::Bucket TheBucket
  my-existing-bucket-name already exists
```

How can I start managing *existing* resources with CloudFormation without recreating them? Or is it impossible by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a new bucket and sync the data from the old bucket to the new bucket. I have not seen a way to use an modify an existing S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The resources section of a cloud formation template defines which resources should be created by cloud formation. Try refering to the existing resources by defining them as parameters instead.

Comment: I would like to **manage** i.e. also adjust the resource, e.g. change cors_rules etc. Not just refer via parameter.

Comment: I am afraid that this will not work with cloudformation. Or I would better tell that I don´t know how this might work. 

The idea of cloudformation is to build your infrastructure based on templates and does not focus on manipulation of existing ressources. The approach in cloudformation would rather be deleting all and building from scratch then to change existing ressources.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import it by using the "Import resources into stack" option:

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html

As the documentation explains, you should add a `"DeletionPolicy": "Retain"` attribute to the already existing resources in your stack.